# how to make skills and their animations in opengl ? are skills 3d model or 2d?

Tags: opengl, c++

1)slash effect
2)area skills like dota2 crystal maiden ulti and first skill
3)over an enemy skills example dota2 crystal maiden second skill

how they make in opengl

i know opengl billboards way and texture atlas i can make basic flame effect with using these 2 way together.
But how they make others ? area skills are 3d model animation ? then its texture is changing every frame? over an enemy skills can 3d model i think? how they make skills transparent ? with glblend ? what is best way to make them sorry for bad english i searched but i couldn't find any suggestion help please 
im using c++,sdl,opengl

Comment: What do you mean by "skills"? Can you upload some images about what you have tried and what you want to achieve?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4MXPGjgdvw i mean like these area skills

Comment: Okay those are called "particle systems". I'm not sure how to actually make them, but i think loading a textured quad under the player, and other little quads for the actual particoes, should do the trick

Comment: i can make billboards and texture atlas maybe their name can be particle systems. i mean tutorial 13 http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/particles-instancing/ fire effects or fog effects but inside youtube link area skills same ? then i will make quads and bilboarding them like these tutorial but area skills looks like have depth they can be 3d model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you seem very confused.

You want to create an visual effect whenever the player attacks another player. These are called **Particle Systems**. Here is a *simple* definition of a texture atlas and billboarding:

### Texture Atlas

A texture atlas looks something like this:

[image]

all it does is storing a bunch of textures in one single image, so that we can specify some coordinates(relative to this texture atlas) and get a specific texture.

### Billboards

Billboarding let's you rotate something(a quad in this case) towards the camera, so that the object is always facing you.

### Making these effects:

To make these effects, we need to use particle systems and animated quads(simple textured quads with an animation). Here is an example seen in the video:

[image]

[image]

Basically, you need a textured quad, that gets spawned onto the terrain (looks like it's projected onto the terrain, but this is the easiest way i can think of), once that is done, you need to spawn some particle systems(the fire) relative to the position of the quad.

For the other particle systems like this one:

[image]

all you need to do is get a position on the terrain, and spawn the 3D models on top of that position.

Comment: my last question to understand good i made picture which one fire area skill ? https://imgur.com/ZvUSPmC or https://imgur.com/2YE4eul and thank you too much your answers

Comment: @EmreKaya well generally, for particle systems, you should use the second one. The first one can be used to create, when combined with the second, these effects.